# In the modern square of opposition are contradictory relations logically equivalent or not?

Tags: logic

Initially, I suspected no because categorical propositions that have contradictory relations according to the modern square of opposition will always have opposing truth values. For instance, if we have the following propositions

A: "All S are P"

[image]

O: "Some S are not P"

[image]

then both cannot be true simultaneously since what they claim oppose or contradict each other, so proposition O being true would necessitate proposition A is false, and vice versa. But I'm confused when my textbook (Patrick Hurley's *A Concise Introduction to Logic,* 12 e., pg. 216) says the statement ~A: "it is false that all S are P" makes the claim that "All S are P" is false and shows that its Venn diagram matches proposition O's Venn diagram.

[image]

The author then concludes

> as the diagram shows, "it is false that all S are P" is actually a particular proposition.

Which I interpret to mean ~A is equivalent to O since their diagrams match.

Since ~A is equivalent to saying "All S are P" is false and ~A's diagram matches O's diagram, then doesn't that mean proposition A being false and proposition O being true have the same Venn diagram and thus are logically equivalent? Or expressed symbolically, since ~A = A(F) and ~A = O(T) then A(F) = O(T)?

Comment: You are confused because you are literally reading instead of understanding concepts. The concept you seem to be unaware of is PROPOSITION. Philosophers don't read SENTENCES. They understand concepts & go from there.They try to get the intention of communication. So a proposition is a form of communication that expresses an idea to another human being regardless the WORD literally. A bell is not called a bell in MANDARIN. There is a different way to say the same thing. In FRENCH there is a different way, etc. To say ALL are not or NOT ALL is actually saying an O proposition from the start.

Comment: How is the first diagram to be interpreted? What do the red lines mean?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder According to the author the red lines indicate emptiness and the 'X' mark indicates existence.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder The first diagram illustrates the statement "No members of S are outside P," and the second diagram illustrates "At least one S exists that is not a P." These are the Boolean interpretation of the statements in the question prompt.

Comment: It could have been much clearer though if emptiness wss just illustrated by, well, nothing. And an element, or more, by a single cross. But anyhow, in the first Venn there is no element in A. In the second there is. What exactly is the problem of logic? Can you say it in words?

Comment: The wording of your question is a little odd, but yes, A being false is logically equivalent to O being true. That is what is meant by contradictory pairs: the truth of one entails the falsehood of the other.

Comment: @Bumble I think the error in my thinking was fixating on the notion that logically equivalent statements should have the same truth value. Since A and O have opposing truth values they aren't logically equivalent. Since A being false and O being true is derived from the contradictory relation between A and O  I thought they aren't logically equivalent as well. I failed to recognize that A is false is the negation of A and thus changes the meaning of A to ~A. So while A and O are contradictory and not logically equivalent this does not extend to the relation between ~A and O. Thanks for helping

Comment: What you have said is right, but think of the expression " it is false all s are p " as saying if the category A is not empty then we know for certainty that at least one member of it is not p, thus the O proposition, meaning some s are not p.

Comment: @Bumble Sorry, a little clarification. I interpreted "A is false" to mean A outputs false and "O is true" to mean O outputs true, so I thought they aren't logically equivalent since they have opposing truth values. I didn't realize that "A is false" would change the meaning of A to ~A which will actually output true the same as O and thus be logically equivalent. Hence, "A is false" is equivalent to saying "O is true."

Comment: @Dasem That was actually my first thought when reading the section, but I overthought it and ended up here. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: See [The Traditional Square of Opposition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/) for clarification.